# chalk package issue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

**When I require to chalk package in node js like as **

### index.js

```
 const  chalk  = require('chalk');
 console.log(chalk.bgRed.inverse("hello world"));
 console.log(chalk.blue.inverse('Hello') + ' World' + chalk.red('!'));
```

### package.json

```
{
"name": "npm_mod",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

},
"author": "rahul",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"chalk": "^5.0.0",
"type": "module"
}
}

**when I run code then show the issue and how to deal with this issue without using .mjs file**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089
  throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
  ^
 Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: R:\24-01-22-nodeJs\npm_mod\node_modul
```

json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error above is because you're using the Common.JS module `require` syntax rather than the ES module `import` syntax.

Update:

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
```

to be:

```
import chalk from 'chalk'
```

Comment: Thank you after it uses then it needs to use index.mjs

Comment: It's because chalk uses `export default` rather than `module.exports`.

Comment: thank you for clearing my dought